# Google Analytics JavaScript onClick issues with 'if' statement for hostname

Tags: javascript, html, google-analytics

So basic function works for sending pageview, but I also have onClick events setup in the HTML which are not working within the same function in JavaScript where `if hostname = 'mydomain.com'`.

JavaScript (works fine):

```
(function(w,d){
     var hostname = w.location && w.location.hostname;
     if(hostname == 'mydomain.com'){
         ga("create","UA-104XXXXXX-1",{name:"new"});ga("new.send","pageview");
}})(window,document);
```

If I add another function within this function, the onclick event does not work but pageview still does. Basically there are multiple domains and there is much more to this JavaScript file but the rest pertains to different domains for other countries, etc.

JavaScript (doesn't work fine):

```
(function(w,d){
var hostname = w.location && w.location.hostname;
if(hostname == 'mydomain.com'){
    ga("create","UA-104XXXXXX-1",{name:"new"});ga("new.send","pageview");
    function myFunc() {
        ga('send', 'event', {'eventCategory': 'Video','eventAction': 'click','eventLabel': 'Experience Video','transport': 'beacon'});}
}})(window,document);
```

HTML:

```
<a class="video" data-embed-url="https://www.youtube.com/embed/_xxxxxxx" href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_xxxxxx" onClick=myFunc() target="_blank">
    &nbsp;
</a>
<span>Experience Video</span>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You have a closing `</li>` tag but no opening one... is that just a typo here, or is that coming from your code?

Comment: sorry, typo, updated

Comment: You're declaring the `myFunc` function inside another function... why not declare it elsewhere and just call it there, when needed?

Comment: I tried that but doesn't work, I am under the assumption that I need to add it somewhere after/within the function that detects the domain name. So if hostname = "blah.com" then do a create pageview but also if onClick call myFunc() whilst still hostname = "blah.com"